# Search article for exact match keywords? Standard regex I found doesn't work

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm working with wordpress articles, searching the for certain keywords like "sex" , but not "sexually".

I've tried

```
$string = "Testing by placing the word at the end sex. More words here.";

if ( preg_match("/\sex\b/i", strtolower($string) ) ) {}
```

and

```
$string = "Testing by placing the word at the end sex. More words here.";
if ( preg_match("~\sex\b~", strtolower($string) ) ) {}
```

but both return false.

Obviously in an article, the word can be at the beginning, end, near punctuation, etc. How can I account for this?

Comment: You lost the letter 'b' `~\bsex\b~`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only missing a character - notice the `\b` after sex? That means it's a word boundary. You need another one before the `sex` as well, not `\s` - that means whitespace.

```
$string = "Testing by placing the word at the end sex. More words here.";
if ( preg_match("~\bsex\b~", strtolower($string) ) ) {}
                   ^---- extra b here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$re = "/sex\\b/m"; 
$str = "Testing by placing the word at the end sex. More words here."; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```